# Azure Media Services Playing video without asset and output object

Tags: azure

I'm trying to figure out how i can watch video by this URL https://temptest-euno.streaming.media.azure.net/472e6bc1-92d9-4e52-9dd0-f6b5842d3083/Presentation.ism/manifest here: 
https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ if i deleted an asset and container in storage-account that contains output video (Before i did it, I'd encoded local video using Media Services using SDK .NET)

Comment: I get it , it played only on my PC because of cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it , it played only on my PC because of cache